# How to type in Cantonese in OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard

In *System Preferences* | *Keyboard* | *Input Sources*, you can add any languages you like by tapping <kbd>+</kbd> button. The list contains Simplified and Traditional language, but it doesn't have Cantonese.

I wonder why it does not contain Cantonese, even though it has some too minor languages like Telugu, Oriya, or even Ainu.

Is it still possible to type in Cantonese in OS X, with possibly pinyin?

Comment: [**This site**](http://blog.theoryspace.com/2009/01/05/how-to-type-chinese-on-a-mac-with-cantonese-pinyin/) may help you figure this out.

Comment: Not sure if this will be of any help however have a look at: [FCIM — a Cantonese Phonetic Input Method](http://members.shaw.ca/akochoi/articles/FCIM-a-cantonese-phonetic-input-method/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use 3rd party input method named "RIME".

1. You can download RIME by goto: http://rime.im/
2. Unzip downloaded file and run Installation.
3. After install was successfully, you need to login your account again.
4. Click on Squirrel Input Method icon (on top menu) and choose `Settings...`.
5. You will see list of setting files, open file named `default.yaml` and edit like below:
   [image]
6. After editing, save file and close.
7. Click on `Squirrel` icon then choose `Deploy`.
8. You now can type Cantonese!
   `zuk nei cing gung` -> 祝你成功

Sorry I can attach only one photo.